# Generator functions dont show my data, how to access it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, generator, redux-saga

I have to invoke an API using sagas and generator function. Here is my code:

```
export function* fetchCreate(data) {
  try {
    const options = jsonBodyOptions(data);
    const tagResponse = yield call(
      fetchJson,
      apiPath + '/fetch',
      tagOptions
    );
    return tagResponse;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export function* callFetch(data)  {
   const response = fetchCreate(data);
}
```

If I print `fetchCreate()`, I see Generator function printed.

I want to invoke that generator function from another function in the same file. I mainly want the response from that function but basically its returning a generator. How can I retrieve the response from it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `yield call(...)`

```
export function* callFetch(data) {
   const response = yield call(fetchCreate, data);
}
```

If `fetchJson`returns a promise, then you can optionally convert `fetchCreate` into a plain function that returns a promise instead of a generator because `yield call` works with functions that return promises.

```
export function fetchCreate(data) {
  try {
    const options = jsonBodyOptions(data);
    return fetchJson(apiPath + '/fetch', tagOptions);    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```